# Obtaining room/area information from Forge api

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit

I need to get room/area objects with the hierarchy of linked objects from the *Revit* model via *Forge*. Right now I am using [this project](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/model.derivative-nodejs-sample) as a starting point. Unfortunately, the room information is lost. As far as I understand, it is removed during the translation process. There are some workarounds like [this one](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2016/06/getting-room-information-for-revit-models-in-the-forge-viewer.html), but it doesn't seem to work for our case. Is there any straightforward way to retrieve room information from *rvt* in *Forge*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is not directly way to get room information via the Forge translator, there are still some workarounds to archive this:

- Open Revit project with room elements only via the Navisworks, and upload to Forge for translation, use this result as the secondary model of your viewer app as well.
- Extract room info. and object relationships via Revit API, and use external mapping feature of the Forge Viewer to rebuild partial relationships between elements and rooms, if room geometry info. is not required.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense

Comment: Eason, I've tried the first option and room/area information is there for NWC file. However, I need to get all objects which are inside the room. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can use bounding box comparison to check this, i.e. to check whether geometry vertices of a object are contained in the bounding box of specific room. This approach can be used in the Forge Viewer, Revit and Navisworks. Here is a example to do this via the Forge Viewer. Hope this help.

https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.BoundingBox

Comment: Just checked the result of GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties  Room information is actually there! Didn't notice it at the first time. Thanks, Eason, your advice really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately room information is not exposed through the Forge translation at the moment. We have a change request pending about it because several developers have been asking this feature. It will be provided in the future but at the moment the best workaround is the link that you pointed out. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Philippe. Do you have any estimation when this feature will be ready?

Comment: I can't give you an estimate unfortunately