# Autodesk Forge randomly loses object and room information

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, revit

I'm using *Autodesk Forge* to integrate with our remodeling tool. In particular, I need to count objects of different families and types and determine to what room they actually belong. I use *Model Derivative API* for this purpose. To keep the room/area information I convert *.rvt* files to *.nwc* files as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128417/obtaining-room-area-information-from-forge-api). However, when I retrieve data with `GET /modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties` I face the following problems from time to time:

1. Room information sometimes disappears from Objects for some reason
2. Objects disappear from result data for some reason (but they seem to exist when I browse them in A360)

I have no idea, what can be the reason for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have no explanation for the disappearance of room data or objects for you.

If you can provide a [reproducible case](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b) demonstrating that, I will gladly pass it on to the development team for analysis.

If you are interested in an immediate reliable solution and full control, which I assume is the case, I would suggest following the second bullet item in the advice provided by Eason in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128417/obtaining-room-area-information-from-forge-api) that you refer to above:

- Extract all the room information and object relationships you are interested in via the Revit API, store that data somewhere yourself, and use it later on wherever you like to your heart's content.

Then you will be completely safe and independent of all other components and their unpredictable behaviour.

If the only information that you need is the room containing each family instance, I can even implement a suitable Revit add-in for you.

Another suggestion that might help, if that is indeed the data you require: determine that information in a Revit add-in and attach it to each family instance in your own personal shared parameter. That will ensure that it remains intact through the translation process. Afaik, all shared parameter data is retained, independent of other behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jeremy.  I'll try to reproduce this with our designer, but he claims that he used exact same steps to create the final layout both for cases when room information exists as well as when it disappears. I understand about Revit API, but we already implemented integration with Forge and we'd like to stay with Forge as it seems more convenient to our workflow. One workaround that I see now is to set room information explicitly with ADSK Zone attribute.